# IntelliJ Live Template: modified setters template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-templates

Is anyone know how to set up a live template in intellij for doing specialized setters 
- i'm using v5, but I accept with pleasure knowledge for a more recent release) -

My first need is a firePropertyChange setter:

```
public final static String $PROPERTY$ = "$property$"
public void set$Property$($TYPE$ $property$) {
    Object oldValue = this.$property$;
    this.$property$ = $property$;
    firePropertyChange($PROPERTY$, oldValue, $property$);
}
```

I have a semi-working version that generate the implementation with variables defined like this:
$property$ --> completeSmart()
$PROPERTY$ --> completeSmart()

My second need is a builder style setter that call the regular setter and then return this after the set:

```
public $THIS_TYPE$ with$Property$($TYPE$ $property$) {
    set$Property$($property$); 
    return this;
}
```

For this one I have nothing really good: I still have to type a lot !

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this

```
private $TYPE$ $NAME$;
public $THIS$ set$BNAME$($TYPE$ $NAME$) {
    this.$NAME$ = $NAME$;
    return this;
}
```

where

```
Type = complete()
NAME = suggestVariableName()
BNAME = capitalize(NAME)
THIS = className()
```

The only Problem ist that className will not work in nested classes as it will return "Outer$Inner" but it should work good enough.