# How to add withX method live template to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I really like the ability to automatically generate getters and setters but I also like to have a set of associated withX methods for each property of a POJO. Is there a way to create a live template for those and use it to generate a withX method for every selected property like the getter/setting generation happens via the generate menu?

I found an example of a live template on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147743/intellij-live-template-modified-setters-template) but I'm not sure how to use it correctly. I can select it from another menu by using the cmd+j shortcut but none of the variables populate...probably because I wasn't prompted to select the properties I want to generate this for.

```
public $THIS_TYPE$ with$Property$($TYPE$ $property$) {
    set$Property$($property$); 
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer from that post?

Comment: That doesn't tell me how/where to put the live template in IntelliJ so that it will generate the method for each property.

Comment: Did you try the builder generator plugin? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6585?pr=

Comment: That's close and may be usable. It sort of makes me think there's no easy way for me to accomplish what I want without writing the code to do it. Not surprising, if that's true. Since that plugin is open source, maybe I can contribute to it.

Comment: Live templates are meant for interactive usage. I don't think you can just point it at a class and run it for all members. Here's some more info about them: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

[Fluent setter generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7903-fluent-setter-generator) plugin is not exactly what you asked, but it provides a simple dialog to select target fields, eventually generating for each of them some code like:

```
public $THIS_TYPE$ with$Property$($TYPE$ $property$) {
  this.$property$ = $property$;
  return this;
}
```