# Generate builder methods instead of setters

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I know there are a lot of plugins for generating Builder pattern classes. But what if I have class:

```
public class User {
  private String name;
}
```

and wanted to add method:

```
public class User {
  private String name;

  public User withName(String name){
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to generate such *withXYZ* method?

**SOLVED**

Go to [Template Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getter-and-setter-templates-dialog.html) for setters and add your own template:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static void ##
#else
  $classname ##
#end
with$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
  this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
#if(!$field.modifierStatic)
return this;
#end
}
```

Comment: Related question for Eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294627/generate-setters-that-return-self-in-eclipse and (possibly) IntelliJ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147743/intellij-live-template-modified-setters-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to add a proper getter/setter template. See:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-getters-and-setters.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getter-and-setter-templates-dialog.html